# What would the following datatype be with the combination of a String and Int

Tags: java

```
String str = new String("Hello");
int i = 4;
```

What would be the data type of the combination of the two variables:

```
str + i;
```

Comment: First step: call it *string concatenation*, not the vague *combination*. That first step will get you very close to the answer

Comment: Why don't you print it, and check then?

Comment: Hint: `System.out.println((str + i).getClass().getName());`

Comment: Don't use the `String(String)` constructor: `String str = "Hello"`.

Comment: `str + i;` is a syntax error. `str + i` is an expression, but not a StatementExpression.

Answer (score 0):

"str+i" is called String concatenation because if we append anything with string it is considered as string as default.